# Can't init my project in Vue.js

Tags: ubuntu, npm, vue.js, npm-install

I'm trying init my project in Vue.js but in the last step, i don't get the localhost.

The message error is the next:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /home/rocio/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rocio/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rocio/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find afile.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/rocio/Documentos/calcu_vue/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks for your help me

Comment: Is there a file called "package.json" at the path "/home/rocio/package.json"?  How did you initialize this project?  Did you use `vue-cli`?

Comment: The file "package.json" is in "/home/rocio/package.json". I started it with `vue-cli` and then i did vue pwa (name of app),npm install.And finally npm run dev